# Alesis SamplePad resets itself / possible ground loop?

Tags: drums

I have an [Alesis DM Lite](http://alesis.com/dmlitekit) e-drum kit , an [Alesis SamplePad](http://alesis.com/samplepad) , a [Roland UM-ONE mk2](http://www.roland.com/products/um-one_mk2/) MIDI-to-USB convertor , a [Montarbo Eve 5](http://www.fiveo.it/en/prod/5162/EVE-5) mixer and a MacBook Pro.

Sometimes I use the audio output from both drums (and Songsterr from an iPhone) into an external mixer and noticed that the SamplePad randomly resets itself every 15 minutes or so.

Sometimes I do not use the audio out from drums into the mixer but plug in the USB MIDI outputs into a MacBook Pro and use the oudio out from there. Noticed that the SamplePad does not reset itself.

I stopped using the audio output into the mixer configuration because I'd like to not destroy the equipment.Attached a rough schematics of the complete setup.

Any clues why the SamplePad resets itself ?

Is it a possible "[ground loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_%28electricity%29)" ? The power supplies of both Alesis drums are "wall wart" style, without ground on the plug. Both are mounted using plastic pads, so there is no common ground.

[image]

Comment: latest drivers?, faulty cable, grounding issues (you can get a little tingle from macbook pro cases), audio problem with mac osx (Can it handle 3 soundcards), is it trying to draw power from USB (try a powered hub), do you have your master clock set and everything else as slave

Answer (score 1):

I added ground cables between the Alesis drum brains and the mixer. So far, no more resets.